# Accessing express routes on heroku directly without serving the react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, routes

Express routes can not be reached directly without serving the react-app on heroku.

I have developed a react-app that runs with a node.js / express backend on heroku. Everything within the react-app works fine.

Now i need to access an express route (e.g. https://example.com/api/info) that makes a call to a mongo db and should only return some JSON.

The problem is, that express always serves the react-app. From within the react-app i can however access the express routes and use them for e.g. login/signup (https://example.com/api/users/login). I just can't access them in production on heroku directly without serving the react-app.

Since heroku decides the port on which the express app lives i can't add a proxy to the react-app's package.json

The react-app is build in the root>client folder.
Please find below the root index.js file of the node.js / express server

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');

const keys = require('./config/keys');

const auth = require('./routes/api/auth');
const mail = require('./routes/api/mail');
const newsletter = require('./routes/api/newsletter');

//connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI)
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

const app = express();

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Passport Config
app.use(passport.initialize());
require('./services/passportJwt')(passport);

// Routes
app.use('/api/users', auth);
app.use('/api/mail', mail);
app.use('/api/newsletter', newsletter);

app.get('/api/info', (req, res) => { //ROUTE DOESN'T WORK, SERVES REACT-APP
  res.json({ msg: "Some Info" });
});

// Serve React App in Production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

// Express will serve up production assets, main.js/main.css
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

// Express will serve up the index.html file if it doesn't recognize the route
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

// Use Heroku port or 5000 when in dev
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT);
```

**Expected result:**

When reaching "https://example.com/api/info" a JSON output should be received { "msg": "Some info" }.
Instead the react-app is served and the react-app doesnt recognize the route "api/info" within the react-router.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have the exact same issue! Did u find a solution?